# What's the source in image in ListView QML

Tags: qt, listview, qml, filedialog

I need to realise list of images, which are chosen by user (folder) and implemet it in a list.
I have some trouble with **source** in object **Image**. In this way I see in console "You chose *path*..", but my images doesn't appear. Why? What's the right path for source?

The path isn't static because the user choose a folder with many pictures in it, so what should I do?

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:window;
    visible: true
       FileDialog {
          id: fileDialog;
          nameFilters: ["Image files (*.jpg *.png *.jpeg)"]
          selectFolder: true;
           onAccepted{
                console.log("You chose " + fileDialog.fileUrl
}
                listView.model = fileDialog.fileUrls;
       }
......

      ListView {
         id: listView
         visible: true;
         orientation: Qt.Vertical
         delegate: {
             Image{
               id: img
               width: 40
               height:40
               source: model(????)
} 
}
....

}
```

Comment: Does `source: modelData` work?

Comment: @JarMan no, I've tried to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `fileDialog.fileUrls` gives you. It doesn't give you a list of files in the folder that you chose. It gives you a list of the files or folders that you selected. You still need to search the directory for the files that you want. Thankfully, Qt provides a `FolderListModel` to do that. So here's a cleaned up example that does this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: btn
        text: "Open"
        onClicked: fileDialog.open();
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog;
        selectFolder: true;
        onAccepted: folderModel.folder = fileDialog.fileUrl;
    }

    ListView {
       id: listView
       anchors.top: btn.bottom
       width: 200
       height: 400
       model: FolderListModel {
           id: folderModel
           nameFilters: ["*.jpg", "*.png", "*.jpeg"]
           showDirs: false
       }
       delegate: Image {
            id: img
            width: 40
            height: 40
            source: fileUrl
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. I've tried to write `source: fileDialog.fileUrl`

Comment: The error is: QML Image: Cannot open: file://////path...

Comment: Prior to Qt 5.15, I think it’s supposed to be fileDialog.fileURL

Comment: I've included the "Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1" . It may be error from this?

Comment: It seems like be a continue to my file path. fileDialog.fileUrl + "/" + fileName 
And I've succesfully tried to do this. ))

Comment: Oh, actually, no. Your comment confused me but my code is correct. source should not be fileDialog.fileUrl, it should be folderModel.fileUrl, like I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

First you need add the url paths to the model and then use it. Take care about the file prefix. Something like this :

```
FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog;
        selectFolder: true;
        onAccepted: updateFiles(fileDialog.files)
}

ListView {
           id: listView
           anchors.top: btn.bottom
           width: 200
           height: 400
           model: FolderListModel {
               id: folderModel
           }
           delegate: Image {
                id: img
                width: 40
                height: 40
                source: listView.model.get(index).fileUrl
            }
}

function updateFiles(fileList){
        console.log(fileList)
        console.log("You chose file(s): " + fileList.fileUrls)
        console.log("Num files: " + fileList.length)
        for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
            var path = fileList[i];
            path = stripFilePrefix(path);
            var newFileUrl = {
                "fileUrl": path
            };
            folderModel.append(newFileUrl);
        } 
}

function stripFilePrefix(filePath) {
    if (Qt.platform.os === "windows") {
        return filePath.replace(/^(file:\/{3})|(file:)|(qrc:\/{3})|(http:\/{3})/, "")
    }
    else {
        return filePath.replace(/^(file:\/{2})|(qrc:\/{2})|(http:\/{2})/, "");
    }
}
```